# Keyboard's brightness controll buttons are disabled

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, preferences

My MacBook Pro doesn't adjust the brightness when I hit the brightness controls on my keyboard (F5/F6). I've tried turning off automatic brightness to no avail. How do I use the function printed on the function keys?

[image: brightness control screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/22/keyboard-illumination-locked-its-the-light-sensor/), it's because your light sensor is detecting that you are in too bright of an environment to use the backlit keyboard. Try moving to a darker area, or covering your light sensor to see if it then lets you turn it on.

Comment: I just confirmed this on a 2016 MBP.